# properly updating the board on Game of Life

Tags: python

I'm trying to recreate Conway's "Game of Life" in Python and I'm having some trouble. I can't get the proper updates on the grid. I'm using a list of lists as my grid, and I know that I'm getting the proper neighbors for each cell. I've tried using two copies of the board, denoted as (fin_board and int_board), but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm treating the edges as a hard barrier and not like a torrid.

In the grid is the seed for a glider, which should move to the bottom right.

```
import time
from copy import deepcopy

int_board = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
             [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]

fin_board = int_board

def update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board):
    if curr_obj == " ":
        if neighbors.count("#") == 3:
            fin_board[i][j] = "#"
            # neighbors.clear()
            return fin_board
    if curr_obj == "#":
        if neighbors.count("#") < 2 or neighbors.count("#") > 3:
            fin_board[i][j] = " "
            # neighbors.clear()
            return fin_board
        if neighbors.count("#") == (2 or 3):
            # neighbors.clear()
            return fin_board


def print_board(fin_board):
    string = ''
    for item in fin_board:
        string += ' '.join(item)
        string += '\n'
    print(string)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\n\n\n\n\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = 0
    # print_board(int_board)
    while counter < 5:
        for i in range(len(int_board)):
            for j in range(len(int_board)):
                curr_obj = int_board[i][j]
                neighbors = []
                if (0 < i < 9) and (0 < j < 9):
                    # deals with the inner board only
                    neighbors.extend(
                        (int_board[i - 1][j], int_board[i + 1][j], int_board[i][j + 1], int_board[i][j - 1],
                         int_board[i - 1][j - 1], int_board[i - 1][j + 1], int_board[i + 1][j - 1],
                         int_board[i + 1][j + 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "inner")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                if i == 0 and j == 0:
                    # deals with top left corner
                    neighbors.extend((int_board[i][j + 1], int_board[i + 1][j], int_board[i + 1][j + 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "top-left")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                if i == 0 and j == 9:
                    # deals with top right corner
                    neighbors.extend((int_board[i][j - 1], int_board[i + 1][j], int_board[i + 1][j - 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "top-right")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                if i == 9 and j == 0:
                    # deals with bottom left corner
                    neighbors.extend((int_board[i - 1][j], int_board[i][j + 1], int_board[i - 1][j + 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "bottom-left")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                if i == 9 and j == 9:
                    # deals with bottom right corner
                    neighbors.extend((int_board[i - 1][j], int_board[i][j - 1], int_board[i - 1][j - 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "bottom-right")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                if i == 0 and (0 < j < 9):
                    # deals with top row
                    neighbors.extend(
                        (int_board[i + 1][j], int_board[i][j + 1], int_board[i][j - 1], int_board[i + 1][j - 1],
                         int_board[i + 1][j + 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "top-row")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                if (0 < i < 9) and j == 0:
                    # deals with the left side
                    neighbors.extend(
                        (int_board[i - 1][j], int_board[i + 1][j], int_board[i][j + 1], int_board[i - 1][j + 1],
                         int_board[i + 1][j + 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "left-side")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                if (0 < i < 9) and j == 9:
                    # deals with the right side
                    neighbors.extend(
                        (int_board[i - 1][j], int_board[i + 1][j], int_board[i][j - 1], int_board[i - 1][j - 1],
                         int_board[i + 1][j - 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "right-side")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                if i == 9 and (0 < j < 9):
                    # deals with the bottom row
                    neighbors.extend(
                        (int_board[i - 1][j], int_board[i][j + 1], int_board[i][j - 1], int_board[i - 1][j - 1],
                         int_board[i - 1][j + 1]))
                    update_board(i, j, curr_obj, neighbors, fin_board)
                    # print(neighbors, "\n", (i, j), "bottom-row")
                    # time.sleep(1)

        int_board, fin_board = fin_board, int_board
        print_board(fin_board)
        counter += 1
```

this is the output the code generates.

{

```
      #            
  #   #            
    # #            


         
    #              
      # #          
    # #            
                   
         
                   
      #            
  #                
    # # #          


 
    #              
      # #          
    # #            
      #            
                   
                         
                   
      #            
  #                
    #   #          
    #
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to do the update in-place? Because that won't work for reasons that should be obvious. Also, make the board much smaller so that you can easily visualize what's going on throughout.

Comment: `fin_board = int_board` does not make a copy. Those are both the same board. You need to explicitly make a copy for them to be separate.

Comment: I've tried fin_board = int_board.copy() and that also doesn't work

Comment: @MadPhysicist what do you mean by update in-place?

Comment: `copy` is a shallow copy. The internal rows will be the same. You'd need `deepcopy` from the `copy` module. The way I do it though is create two different lists at the start, and then swap them at the end of each tick.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for that but how would you swap them?

Comment: @A3DPrintedMan The standard Python idiom for swapping two variables is `var1, var2 = var2, var1`. Or you could use the typical way that makes use of a third temporary variable.

Comment: @Carcigenicate. Technically the tuple on the right hand side is a third variable

Comment: @A3DPrintedMan. In-place means that you're modifying the lists as you iterate rather than making a copy. This is a consequence of the shallow copy issue

Comment: @MadPhysicist Technically, but there isn't a named variable introduced like you'd do in a language like C (ignoring math "hacks" that can get around that).